# How to calculate the daily warehouse stock in DAX?

Tags: excel, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a table in SSAS tabular mode that shows how individual pieces of products moved through different sections of a production line:

Product_ID, section_ID, Category_id (product category), time_in (when a product entered the section), time_out (when the product exited the section)

This is how the input table looks like:

[image]

I would like to write a measure in DAX that can show me the stock of each section and product category day-by-day as shown below by counting the number of distinct product ids which were in a particular section on that day.

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2017 Analysis Services in Tabular Mode and Excel Pivot Table for representation.

Comment: So your image is your desired output? Can you show what the input looks like as well?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I have added the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table that has all of the dates that you want to use for your columns. Here's one possibility:

```
Dates = CALENDAR(MIN(ProductInOut[time_in]), MAX(ProductInOut[time_out]))
```

Now create a measure that counts rows in your input table satisfying a condition.

```
ProductCount = 
    VAR DateColumn = MAX(Dates[Date])
    RETURN COUNTROWS(FILTER(ProductInOut,
               ProductInOut[time_in] <= DateColumn &&
               ProductInOut[time_out] >= DateColumn)) + 0
```

Now you should be able to set up a pivot table with `Category_id` on the rows and `Dates[Date]` on the columns and `ProductCount` as the values.

[image: Output Matrix]